# Is it true that after gets are given they are burned/destroyed?

Tags: divorce, legal-documents

I've heard this from several people, but could not find a source.

Comment: They are ripped https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%98_%D7%A4%D7%95

Answer (score 1):

They are cut in a specific way and then kept by the Beth Din for future references. The two parties will receive a document attesting to the divorce

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: I heard this as well years ago, from a Rav who was mesader gittin. The reason he gave was that we don't want people raising objections to details of the get. It was given, the beis din made sure everything was fine, and that's all the rest of us need to know. The beis din gives the woman a document that she's divorced.

Comment: @Double AA: I know it because I was regularly one of the Dayanim in a highly regarded Beth Din for Gittin for nearly 30 years.

Answer (score 0):

It's cut with a box cutter and then kept on file in the Beit Din.

**שולחן ערוך אבן העזר סדר הגט (אחרי סימן קנד)
סעיף פו
ק**

> **ויקרענו שתי וערב.** הגה: ונהגו מעכשיו שהרב המסדר הגט גונזו
> אצלו ואינו נותנו ביד האשה, ואין לשנות. וכל הגט שלא ניתן, אין לקרעו שתי
> וערב, שלא יטעו בו שניתן (מ"כ).

Comment: Why a box cutter?

Comment: Handy, safe, and effective.

Comment: In the Beth Din I was a Dayan in, they used scissors!